# NestJS Unknown authentication strategy "local"

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs, passport-local

I have this code in NestJs with the following files below, but now it says "Unknown authentication strategy "local"",
I've already looked for solutions and they all point to an import error, but I have the localstrategy imported into auth.module and app.module (I've already tested taking it out of app.module but it doesn't change anything.)

app.module.ts

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AppController } from './app.controller';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    import { ThrottlerModule } from '@nestjs/throttler';
    import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
    import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
    import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
    import { LocalStrategy } from './auth/local.strategy';

    @Module({
      imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot(
          'mongodb+srv://user:password@db.db.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        ),
        ThrottlerModule.forRoot({
          ttl: 60,
          limit: 10,
        }),
        AuthModule,
        UsersModule,
      ],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService, LocalStrategy],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

auth.module.ts

```
      import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
  import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
  import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
  import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
  import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
  import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
  import 'dotenv/config';

  @Module({
    imports: [
      UsersModule,
      PassportModule,
      JwtModule.register({
        secret: process.env.JWTSECRET,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
      }),
    ],
    providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
    exports: [AuthService],
  })
  export class AuthModule {}
```

local.strategy.ts

```
      import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
  import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
  import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

  @Injectable()
  export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
      super({ usernameField: 'email' });
    }

    async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
      const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);
      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
      return user;
    }
  }
```

app.controller.ts

```
    import {
  Controller,
  Request,
  Post,
  UseGuards,
  Res,
  Get,
  Body,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { MakeAuthDto } from './auth/dto/make-auth.dto';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './auth/jwt-auth.guard';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './auth/local-auth.guard';
import { Roles } from './utils/decorators/roles.decorator';
import { Role } from './utils/enums/role.enum';
import { RolesGuard } from './utils/guards/roles.guard';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(
    @Body() _: MakeAuthDto,
    @Request() req,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res,
  ) {
    console.log(req.user);
    const access_token = await this.authService.login(req.user);
    res.cookie('jwt', access_token);
    return req.user;
  }

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
  @Roles(Role.Admin)
  @Get('tests')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

local-auth.guard.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

    @Injectable()
    export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

auth.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from 'src/users/users.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UserDocument } from 'src/users/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(email: string, pass: string): Promise<UserDocument | any> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne(email);
    if (user && (await user.compareHash(pass))) {
      const { password, ...result } = user.toObject();
      await this.usersService.updateLastLogin(user._id);
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }

  async login(user: UserDocument): Promise<string> {
    const payload = { email: user.email, sub: user._id, roles: user.roles };
    return this.jwtService.sign(payload);
  }
}
```

jwt-auth.guard.ts

```
        import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

    @Injectable()
    export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

jwt.strategy.ts

```
    import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import 'dotenv/config';

const cookieExtractor = function (req) {
  let token = null;
  if (req && req.cookies) {
    token = req.cookies['jwt'];
  }
  return token;
};

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([cookieExtractor]),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWTSECRET,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, email: payload.email, roles: payload.roles };
  }
}
```

[image]

No similar question on stackoverflow solved my problem, does anyone know what it can be?

Comment: Not sure if this is technically the issue, but with the newest version of passport `0.5.0` you have to call `passport.initialize()` such as `app.use(passport.initialize())` for an express based app. I wonder if that could somehow be the cause.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Where do I need to put this?

Comment: Well in a standard express app it would simply be something like this in a main file [app.js](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/app.js#L36). You could try simply doing a `use` statement in your `main.ts` (initialization file) or similar. `import * as passport from 'passport'; //.. app.use(passport.initialize());`

Comment: Is your `UsersService` request scoped?

Comment: In my case, my AppModule doesn't have LocalStrategy as a provider, just the AuthModule. Could that be causing issues since your AppModule doesn't import Passport? Also, you haven't shared your definition of the AppService, so I can't tell if it uses the strategy or not.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I ended up facing this error due to my organisation of the folder it seems not finding the files `local.strategy` and `jwt.strategy`, in each Guard I had to add a constructor importing the Strategy.

Currently your code like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

Change your file by adding the construct like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  constructor(private readonly localStrategy: LocalStrategy) {
    super();
  }
}
```

If this does not work, the real reason for this error is related to scope request injection, apparently a middleware must be ignoring the execution of the `LocalAuthGuard` middlware. For example: a multi-tenant connection, if you get the name of the database from the request, may end up ignoring the execution of LocalAuthGuard, because in the file `local.strategy.ts` you are using the constructor `private authService: AuthService` and if it really is making multi tenant connection review how you are injecting the repository in your file called `UsersService`.

Hope this helps anyone looking with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this snippet of code:

local.strategy.ts

```
  import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
  import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
  import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

  @Injectable()
  export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
      super({ usernameField: 'email' });
    }

    async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
      const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);
      if (!user) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
      return user;
    }
  }
```

on this line you need to pass in the custom strategy:

```
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'local') {
```